# The program 'tesseract' could not be executed or was not found on your system PATH - Laravel

Tags: python, laravel, pyinstaller

I created an executable using "pyinstaller". It runs fine on terminal in Ubuntu.
But when I ran the executable in a Laravel web app using Symfony process below error was seen in the console->

```
The program 'tesseract' could not be executed or was not found on your
system PATH.
[11805] Failed to execute script 'converttotext' due to unhandled exception!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ocrmypdf/subprocess/__init__.py", line 296, in check_external_program
  File "ocrmypdf/_exec/tesseract.py", line 80, in version
  File "ocrmypdf/subprocess/__init__.py", line 168, in get_version
ocrmypdf.exceptions.MissingDependencyError: The program 'tesseract' did not report its version. Message was:
tesseract: /opt/lampp/lib/libtiff.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblept.so.5)
tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1
 leptonica-1.75.3
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.2) : libpng 1.6.37 : libtiff 4.0.1 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
```

Comment: Ok, so it helps to have some code examples. Currently it is only a guessing game for anyone reading this.

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract is a separate executable. Follow instruction https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html how to add binary into pyinstaller.